# Javascript Canvas how to shoot in 360* from a rotating object

Tags: javascript, canvas, geometry, angle

All my searching comes up with more general arc/sin/cos usage or shooting to the mouse position.
I am looking to aim and fire a projectile with the keyboard and have done a lot of it from scratch, as a noob in a web class doing a project, but I am stuck on this. My current math got me to this mess in firing the shot in the direction the line is currently pointing... (code names cleaned for readability):

```
this.x = x + len * Math.cos(angle);
this.y = y + len * Math.sin(angle);
this.xmov = -((x + len * Math.cos(angle)) - x) / ((y + len * Math.sin(angle)) - y);
this.ymov = ((y + len * Math.sin(angle)) - y) / ((x + len * Math.cos(angle)) - x);

if (Math.abs(this.xmov) > Math.abs(this.ymov)) {
    this.xmove = (this.xmov * Math.abs(this.ymov));
} else {
    this.xmove = this.xmov;
}
if (Math.abs(this.ymov) > Math.abs(this.xmov)) {
    this.ymove = (this.xmov * this.ymov);
} else {
    this.ymove = this.ymov;
}
```

(And here is the full thing http://jsbin.com/ximatoq/edit. A and D to turn, S to fire (on release). Can also hold S while turning.)

... but, you'll see that it only works for 3/8's of it. What is the math to make this fire from a complete circle?

Comment: Why bother with the trigonometry for anything other than determining the new heading when rotating? If you've a line and wish to fire a projectile in the same direction that it points, 2d vectors are sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this as shoot function:

```
this.shoot = function() {
     if (this.fire > 0) {
          this.x = P1gun.x2;
          this.y = P1gun.y2;
          this.xmove = (P1gun.x2 - P1gun.x)/100;
          this.ymove = (P1gun.y2 - P1gun.y)/100;
          this.fire = 0;
          this.firetravel = 1;
     }
}
```

The `/100` can be removed, but you have to reduce the projectile speed.

If you want to shoot gun2 change the P1gun to P2gun.

Comment: Wow, thank you. I knew it was a simple rise/over run problem, and I swear at one point I considered a division by 100, ... but I think I just stared at it too long and when near vertical/horizontal the steep difference threw me off. And I need to get more comfortable with classes/object usage. The first part of this.x = P1gun.x2; this.y = P1gun.y2; is a huge duh moment. Thank you very much. Now to learn collision...

Answer (score 0):

### Normalising a vector.

To control the speed of something using a vector, first make the length of the vector 1 unit long (one pixel). This is commonly called normalising the vector, and sometimes it's called the unit vector. Then you can multiply that vector by any number to get the desired speed.

To normalise a vector first calculate its length, then divide it by that value.

```
function normalizeVector(v){
    var len = Math.sqrt(v.x * v.x + v.y * v.y);
    v.x /= len;
    v.y /= len;
    return v;
}
```

**Trig**

When you use trig to create a vector it is also a unit vector and does not need to be normalised.

```
  function directioToUnitVector(angle){ // angle in radians
     return {
         x : cos(angle),
         y : sin(angle)
     }
```

**Why normalise**

Many many reasons, you build almost everything from unit vectors.

One example, if you have two points and want to move from one to the next at a speed of 10 pixels per second with a frame rate of 60frame per second.

```
 var p1 = {};
 var p2 = {};
 p1.x = ?  // the two points
 p1.y = ?
 p2.x = ?
 p2.y = ?
 // create a vector from p1 to p2
 var v = {}
 v.x = p2.x -p1.x;
 v.y = p2.y -p1.y;
 // Normalize the vector
 normalizeVector(v);

 var frameRate = 1/60;  // 60 frames per second
 var speed = 10; // ten pixels per second

 function update(){
     // scale vec to the speed you want. keeping the vec as a unit vec mean
     // you can also change the speed, or use the time for even more precise
     // speed control.
     p1.x += v.x * (speed * frameRate);
     p1.y += v.y * (speed * frameRate);
     // draw the moving object at p1

     requestAnimationFrame(update)
  }
```

> **NOTE** when normalizing you may get a vector that has no length. If your code is likely to create such a vector you need to check for the zero length and take appropriate action. Javascript does not throw an error when you divide by zero, but will return `Infinity`, with very strange results to your animations.